# How to set GridView EditItemTemplate Textbox to take maximum cell Width?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have one Gridview with 5 columns including the edit column.  When I click Edit I would like the last column EditItemTemplate Textbox 'The_Title' to take up the maximum width of the cell.  It never does! (I can shrink the tbTitle with the Width attribute but not increase)  I have tried many things including 'GridView1_RowDataBound'.   What am I missing.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 4)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("style", "white-space:nowrap;padding:0px;margin:0px;width:500px");

        }
    }
}
```

GridView .aspx - only thing on the page no update panel (1 GV and 1 SqlDataSouce).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="1000px" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="Red" Width="100%"  />        
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="The_Source" SortExpression="The_Source">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSrc" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("The_Source") %>' Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSrc" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("The_Source") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section" SortExpression="Section">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Section") %>' Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Section") %>' Width="50px"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="The_Title" SortExpression="The_Title" HeaderStyle-Width="500px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Red">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                                <div style="white-space:nowrap;background-color:blue;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                              <asp:TextBox ID="tbTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("The_Title") %>' Width="500px" style="white-space:nowrap;"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("The_Title") %>' Width="500px"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                
                <ControlStyle BackColor="#3399FF" />                
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

// Result image
[image: Result GridView1]

Any clues would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Could be so many different things that are causing this. First Off is the behavior consistent with all browsers? versions? Compatibility mode?
You should use some sort tool (F12 in IE) to inspect the resulting mark-up, this will help you see what is truly going on.

Comment: @DaniDev Yes, this is across all three browsers.  IE, Chrome, FF.

Comment: what is your default test browser?  you should be able to inspect the resulting mark-up (HTML) for your text box and tinker with it to see what is causing the size restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Browser developer tools, you should be able to inspect the resulting mark-up (HTML) for your text box and tinker with it to see what is causing the size restriction.

**IE** developer tools (**F12**) will show you the hierarchical (cascading) order where the width setting is being defined.

Answer (score 1):

Tested your GridView. The TextBox `tbTitle` is 500 px wide, just as expected. There is probably some bootstrap or other css overwriting the width.

What happens if you add a class for it?

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbTitle" runat="server" CssClass="fullWidth" Text='<%# Bind("The_Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>

.fullWidth {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Or set it inline as `!important`. If that does not work then there is probably something else going on.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbTitle" runat="server" style="width: 100% !important" Text='<%# Bind("The_Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Same result. No change.  Is there away to disable bootstrap on a single page to test your theory ?

Comment: Try it inline. Updated my answer.

Comment: Tried inline your way first and next with this as a sanity check style="width: 100% !important;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:green". Both inline both no change.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: IE developer tools (F12) will show you the hierarchical (cascading) order where the width setting is being set.

Comment: GOD BLESS BOTH OF YOU !!! (And I'm an atheist !!!).  Found the issue. VDWWD was correct with the clue that some where VS2013 was placing a auto tag somewhere @DaniDev was right in that the best way to find it was using IE's Inspector.  It was showing a 'max-width: 280px' begin set in my Site.css.  A quick search and delete.....Solved!!! I could kiss both of you. Can I give both of you check marks ?

Comment: Glad you were able to find the help you needed. I can post an answer and you can up vote if you like.